# ReferenceError: formValidation is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to call the function... But i keep getting this error.. How do I Solve this?

The error I'm getting is: *index.html?email=&gebruikersnaam=&wachtwoord=&submit=Submit:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: formValidation is not defined
at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (index.html?email=&gebruikersnaam=&wachtwoord=&submit=Submit:1)
onsubmit @ index.html?email=&gebruikersnaam=&wachtwoord=&submit=Submit:1*

**HTML**

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/controllers/registerController.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/registrationValidation.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Awesome Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../assets/js/controllers/registerController.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/registrationValidation.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bodytop">
<div class="container h-100 h200">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="user_card">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="brand_logo_container">
          <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/pinterest-circle-logo-png-transparent.png"
               class="brand_logo" alt="Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

        <form name="registratieForm" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
          <div class="input-group mb-3 registreer-form">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="email">
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="gebruikersnaam">
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" class="form-control input_pass" value="" placeholder="wachtwoord">
          </div>




          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn login_btn">Registreer</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function formValidation() {
  var email = document.registration.email;
  var wachtwoord = document.registration.wachtwoord;
  var gebruikersnaam = document.registration.gebruikersnaam;


  if (email_validation(email, 5, 12)) {
    if (wachtwoord_validation(wachtwoord, 7, 12)) {
      if (allLetter(gebruikersnaam)) {
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function wachtwoord_validation(wachtwoord,mx,my)
{
  var wachtwoord_len = wachtwoord.value.length;
  if (wachtwoord_len == 0 ||wachtwoord_len >= my || wachtwoord_len < mx)
  {
    alert("Wachtwoord hoort niet leeg te zijn / lengte moet tussen de "+mx+" tot "+my);
    wachtwoord.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function allLetter(gebruikersnaam)
{
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(gebruikersnaam.value.match(letters))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert('Gebruikersnaam mag alleen alfabetische letters hebben.');
    gebruikersnaam.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function email_validation(email)
{
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if(email.value.match(mailformat))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Het ingevulde email is ongeldig!");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You have scripts outside the document. The comment tells you to include them inside the head tags. 2. jQuery ALWAYS come before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

1. not sure why you have scripts outside the document.
2. jQuery MUST be loaded before bootstrap and use the same version of CSS as the JS
3. Typo: The form name is registratieForm
4. You really need a height on that image

   ```
   var email = document.registratieForm.email;
   var wachtwoord = document.registratieForm.wachtwoord;
   var gebruikersnaam = document.registratieForm.gebruikersnaam;
   ```

```js
function formValidation() {
  var email = document.registratieForm.email;
  var wachtwoord = document.registratieForm.wachtwoord;
  var gebruikersnaam = document.registratieForm.gebruikersnaam;


  if (email_validation(email, 5, 12)) {
    if (wachtwoord_validation(wachtwoord, 7, 12)) {
      if (allLetter(gebruikersnaam)) {}
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function wachtwoord_validation(wachtwoord, mx, my) {
  var wachtwoord_len = wachtwoord.value.length;
  if (wachtwoord_len == 0 || wachtwoord_len >= my || wachtwoord_len < mx) {
    alert("Wachtwoord hoort niet leeg te zijn / lengte moet tussen de " + mx + " tot " + my);
    wachtwoord.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function allLetter(gebruikersnaam) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (gebruikersnaam.value.match(letters)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Gebruikersnaam mag alleen alfabetische letters hebben.');
    gebruikersnaam.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function email_validation(email) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (email.value.match(mailformat)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Het ingevulde email is ongeldig!");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.brand_logo {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Awesome Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../assets/js/controllers/registerController.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/js/registrationValidation.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bodytop">
  <div class="container h-100 h200">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
      <div class="user_card">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="brand_logo_container">
            <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/pinterest-circle-logo-png-transparent.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Logo">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">

          <form name="registratieForm" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
            <div class="input-group mb-3 registreer-form">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="email">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="gebruikersnaam">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" class="form-control input_pass" value="" placeholder="wachtwoord">
            </div>




            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
              <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn login_btn">Registreer</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```